# Как сохранить и прочитать переменные в файле? lua

Tags: lua

Есть переменные:

x = 0

y = 20

Как сохранить их и прочитать в файле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример чтения файла

```
local x, y                                 -- Объявить переменные локальными
local file, err = io.open("test.txt", "r") -- Открыть файл для чтения
if file then                               -- Проверить, что он открылся
    x = file:read()                        -- Прочитать первую строку в переменную x (без преобразования в число)
    y = file:read()                        -- Прочитать вторую строку в переменную y (тоже без преобразования)
    file:close()                           -- Закрыть файл
else
    io.stderr:write(err, '\n')             -- Если не открылся, то вывести ошибку
    x = 0                                  -- И присвоить переменным
    y = 20                                 -- значения по умолчанию
end
```

Считывание данных можно сократить, используя [строки форматирования](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-file:read)

```
x, y = file:read("*number", "*number") -- Теперь это либо числа, либо nil (есть проверка формата)
```

Пример записи файла (при ошибке передаст её вызывателю)

```
local file = assert(io.open("test.txt", "w")) -- Открыть файл для записи (assert проверит ошибку)
file:write(x, '\n')                           -- Записать значение переменной x и символ перевода строки
file:write(y, '\n')                           -- Записать значение переменной x и символ перевода строки
assert(file:close())                          -- Закрыть файл (или выбросить ошибку)
```

Соответствующий [раздел документации](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.html).

Comment: Ошибка: attempt to index global 'file' (a nil value)

Comment: Файла test.txt нет в каталоге. Можете поменять местами запись и чтение. Или создать файл вручную и записать в него 0 и 20 по одному в строку.

Comment: Или можно создать ещё один вопрос "Как обрабатывать ошибки открытия файла?"

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin он настолько элементарный, что я даже не представляю, что там объяснять. Стоит ли мне разжевать присваивание, условные операторы, обращение к методам?

Comment: Cоветую глянуть на а) локальные переменные везде, где можно б) `assert`, где нужно (в примере с чтением ошибка хандлится, а с записью `io.open` неплохо бы обернуть).

Comment: @val беспокоит, что ответ на вопрос про чтение и запись в файл стремительно уходит от сути, обрастая дополнительными подробностями.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Тогда сейчас кину правку, там всего ничего вписать.

Comment: @val а теперь поставьте себя на место автора вопроса. Представьте, что вообще вы вообще не знаете lua, да и программировать толком не умеете. Разобрались бы с ответом?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Попробовал. Ответ стал чуть менее магией и побудил загуглить про обработку ошибок. ИМХО, лучше натолкнуть на неизвестное, чем его прятать (сам при изучении lua от подобного не раз страдал).